# No error but `md-table` not rendering data ( `connect()` is not called)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to implement  [Angular Material Table.](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). The problem is that I do not get any error but there is no output. I have not used the typical example but am trying to implement using my own data.

- What am I missing?
- Does the `dataSource` object have a specific dataformat?

Please correct me if I am wrong but as per my understanding of below documentation , it should work if `dataSource` is set to an `array`.

> Data is provided to the table through a DataSource. When the table receives a data source, it calls the DataSource's connect function which returns an observable that emits an array of data. Whenever the data source emits data to this stream, the table will update.

Below is my code.

**HTML** :

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <label> Testing </label>
  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">


    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="dbquery">
      <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>dbquery </md-header-cell>
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.dbquery}} </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="columns"></md-header-row>
    <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></md-row>

  </md-table>
</div>
```

**TS** :

```
    import { Component, OnInit , Input,OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tabledata : any;
  private headers : any;
  private columns : any;

  public dataSource: BindDataTableSource | null;

  dataChange: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([{}]);
  get data(): [{}] { console.log("getData is called ",this.dataChange.value) ;return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor(){};
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new BindDataTableSource(this);

    this.headers = this.tabledata.headers;
    this.columns = this.tabledata.columns;

    console.log("inside nginit ",this.dataSource);
    console.log(this.headers);
    console.log(this.columns);

  }


}

export class BindDataTableSource extends DataSource<any>{

  constructor(private datatable : DataTableComponent){

    super();
    console.log(this.datatable.tabledata.data);
    for(let index = 0 ; index < this.datatable.tabledata.data.length ; index++){
//      console.log(this.datatable.tabledata.data[index]);
      this.datatable.dataChange.next(this.datatable.tabledata.data[index]);
    }

//     this.datatable.dataSource = this.datatable.data.data;
//    console.log("inside bindatatablsource ",this.datatable.dataSource);

  }
  connect() : Observable<[{}]> {

    console.log("connect is called ->  ",this.datatable.dataChange);
    return this.datatable.dataChange;
  }

  disconnect(){};

}
```

And below is my **console** output

[image: Console Output]

Appreciate the help.

P.S - the docs are terrible.

Comment: As you can see, `connect()` isn't being called. `dataSource` should have the type `BindDataTableSource | null` and you should assign that in your OnInit with `this.dataSource = new BindDataTableSource(this)`..

Further, it isn't clear how `dataChange` works? Is a parent component calling next on it?

Comment: Also what have you found difficult about the docs? They're fresh and haven't been refined much yet, but if you can point out specific issues (or make a PR), then they can be improvied

Comment: @WillHowell I made the changes as per your suggestions but `connect()` is still not being called. I know that in documentation it says that it will be called when the table receives data source, but it is not that clear.

Comment: I can't explain why `connect` is not called, but some other things I see are that (if your table were to render) it would only have one column and one row. You have only defined a single cdkColumnDef for `dbquery` and your `dataChange` subject emits a single value several times... You probably want to be emitting an array of values a single time.  If you can post a plunker, I can see better

Comment: Will Howell, please see the plnkr below. It seems to use BindDataTableSource, but that class does not appear to be defined in the plnkr, or imported:     https://plnkr.co/edit/BBdEKJ4WnJVBetZR4AkY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5593

work around is mentioned in the bug.

one needs to force change detection.

this.changeDetector.detectChanges();

worked for me after this.